# SQL Query date from two tables

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I am trying to write a query...

```
select * from inventoryinfo, purchaseorderiteminfo
where inventoryinfo.qtyinstock < inventoryinfo.minqty
and inventoryinfo.AISTATUS = '1'
and inventoryinfo.category <> 'Noritsu Parts'
and inventoryinfo.itemcode = purchaseorderiteminfo.itemcode
and purchaseorderiteminfo.status = '0'
```

It returns 10 items

On another table this query shows what items are ordered and on their way

```
select * from purchaseorderiteminfo
where status = '0'
```

It returns 8 items

I want to join these two query's to list the 10 items, so I have:

```
select * from inventoryinfo, purchaseorderiteminfo
where inventoryinfo.qtyinstock < inventoryinfo.minqty
and inventoryinfo.AISTATUS = '1'
and inventoryinfo.category <> 'Noritsu Parts'
and inventoryinfo.itemcode = purchaseorderiteminfo.itemcode
and purchaseorderiteminfo.status = '0'
```

BUT, it only shows 8 items because the other 2 items do not have an open PO for an order for them.  Is there a way to have a list with all 10 items, even 2 of them don't have data in the purchaseorderiteminfo table?

Comment: inventoryinfo left join purchaseorderiteminfo should get you all records, even the ones that do not have a PO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a`left join`between the tables. This gets all rows from the main table, and the matching from the left joined.

```
select * from inventoryinfo
left join purchaseorderiteminfo on inventoryinfo.itemcode = purchaseorderiteminfo.itemcode and purchaseorderiteminfo.status = '0'
where inventoryinfo.qtyinstock < inventoryinfo.minqty
and inventoryinfo.AISTATUS = '1'
and inventoryinfo.category <> 'Noritsu Parts'
```

You can also use aliases for the tables to shorten the query a bit:

```
select * from inventoryinfo i
left outer join purchaseorderiteminfo p on i.itemcode = p.itemcode and p.status = '0'
where i.qtyinstock < i.minqty
and i.AISTATUS = '1'
and i.category <> 'Noritsu Parts'
```

Also notice that I replaced your old-style implicit joins:

```
from table1, table2
where table1.key = table2.key
```

with the explicit syntax used in ANSI standard SQL-92 and later:

```
FROM table1
LEFT [OUTER] JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
-- the OUTER keyword is optional in many databases.
```

See [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) for some reasons why you want to do this.

Comment: +1 . . . I would have upvoted for either suggestion.

Comment: Thank you!  I am using an old version of Adaptive server anywhere and it doesn't look like it support left join.  I get a syntax error.  Any other method to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @JeffreyLazo How old is your Adaptive Server? ASE has supported ANSI syntax since at least 1999. And what error did you get?

Comment: Unfortuntaly we are running ASE 7.

Comment: Ok, not sure what syntax that supports, try `left outer join`instead of `left join` . I think that should work. Apparently the `outer`keyword became optional in ASE 8.